# How do I resolve error while plotting in Matlab?

Tags: linux, matlab, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to plot in MATLAB Version 9.4 (R2018a). I tried the following code (given as example here https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

```
x=0:pi/100:2*pi; 
y=sin(x);
plot(x,y)
```

But I got the following error:

No appropriate method, property, or field 'Type' for class 'matlab.graphics.GraphicsPlaceholder'.

Error in newplot>ObserveAxesNextPlot (line 134)

if ~strcmp(fig.Type,'figure')

Error in newplot (line 89)

ax = ObserveAxesNextPlot(ax, hsave);

My operating system is Ubuntu 14.04

Can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Shot in the dark, but could you try to run matlab with opengl  (Bash/terminal: `matlab -softwareopengl`) . I had similar problem in 16.04 which was solved that way.

Comment: The same problem addressed by the Mathworks [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/376991-matlab-2017b-plotting-error?requestedDomain=true&nocookie=true).

Comment: `matlab -softwareopengl` worked! Thank you! @LeanderMoesinger

Comment: I am having the same issue.